# My paper is not shown in my Google Scholar profile

Tags: google-scholar

It has been a month since my paper was accepted and published. The paper is not yet assigned to any issue in the journal, but it is published and available via springer.com. The paper is in the Google Scholar list of papers for the corresponding author, but it is not yet shown in my list of papers. When I search for it, no result is returned

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Scholar's automated indexing algorithm makes mistakes.  It can overlook some of your papers and it may also list some papers in your profile that are not yours.

To add a paper, press the "+" button and select "Add articles" to add articles off a list of possible matches Google found.  Or press "Add article manually" to enter title, authors, journal, etc., manually.

To delete a paper that's not yours, click the checkbox beside it and then click "Delete".

Comment: I have the same problem. I added the paper manually, but when I click on the paper link it does not take me to the actual link of the paper. I tried searching for the paper by pressing '+' and 'Add Articles', and it shows that the paper is already in my profile, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Google scholar takes quite some time to update the database. Anyway, you can always add your articles manually.

Comment: Why the corresponding author has the paper in its list?

Comment: Maybe you have a slightly different name in the article and your Google scholar.

Comment: Then why by searching its name it is not shown?

Comment: Probably because the corresponding author added it manually